# What is a simple way to “2 out of 3”-secure a mnemonic phrase without computers?

Tags: keys, secret-sharing, pen-and-paper

I'm working on a safe way to store a mnemonic key.

- It's 24 words long.
- Each word is 11 bits of entropy
- I want to store it in 3 locations
- One plate should not allow you to unlock the code
- Two plates should allow you to unlock the code

Now to the interesting challenges:

- If I die, I want my loved ones to be able to extract the mnemonic keys. They know nothing of cryptography.
- To protect it from fire, I'm etching it on metallic plates so the instructions for unlocking can't be to long or complicated.
- I want it to last for at least 100 years, so I can't rely on any current computer software.

My fist idea was to just leave 8 different words out of each plate, but that is just 88 bits of entropy, a bit to little to crack(or is it). There are also tools to do Shamir's Secret Sharing Scheme, with mnemonic phrases, but it's not really something you do without a computer. Is there some other good way to increase the bits of entropy without to much complication? Maybe mixing up the words or add extra words or something?

Comment: [Crossposted on security.se](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/171225/what-is-a-simple-way-to-2-out-of-3-secure-a-24-word-phrace-without-computers)

Comment: I’m putting this Q on hold, as [copy-and-paste cross-posting](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/171225/26145) is deprecated at the StackExchange network.

Comment: I didn't know you were not allowed to do that... which community do you think is more suitable for this question?